# How to remove shadows from high resolution imagery (IKONOS 1M)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, envi, ikonos

I have dataset imagery comes from IKONOS satellite, the dataset contains "imagery with 1m resolution - metadata - rpc file", the metadata file contains the information about "Sun Angle Azimuth - Sun Angle Elevation - Acquisition Date/Time", so is there any way to remove the shadows area from the imagery data?

[metadata http://rghost.net/6cb99zmLy/image.png](http://rghost.net/6cb99zmLy/image.png)

edit: i used GCP with Socet GXP to generate high resolution DEM (1m).

Comment: Do you have a digital elevation model with the same resolution? Then you could calculate the length and position of shadows.

Comment: yeah, i  used GCP  with Socet GXP to generate high resolution DEM (1m) from it.

Comment: http://rghost.net/7JkBw6FpP/image.png

Comment: http://rghost.net/7gMxGfKwZ/image.png

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue about topographic correction. For instance, you can refer to this paper "Topographic correction algorithm for remotely sensed data accounting for indirect irradiance" or "A Physically-Based Model to Correct Atmospheric and Illumination Effects in Optical Satellite Data of Rugged Terrain".